# How to respond to a question that contains a minor bug

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [strcat_s adds strange characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893606/strcat-s-adds-strange-characters).

The problem can be fixed by changing the line:

```
char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2] ;
```

to

```
char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2] = {0};
```

This is minor fix to the code that may or may not help other SO users.

1. Do such questions deserve to be closed?
2. Does this question fall under **"Closing -> Off-Topic > This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."** category?

**Update**

Another question posted the same day that falls under the category of **"needing minor changes to the code to fix the problem"** - [Trouble with using calloc with an array and returning a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894776/trouble-with-using-calloc-with-an-array-and-returning-a-pointer)

Comment: No; its not a typo. Sounds like an answer (especially if you explain *why* that is necessary). Given the simple nature, it *could* be a duplicate.

Comment: Forgetting to zero-terminate a C string is a duplicate for *thousands* of questions.  Digging up such a dup is hard work, posting a comment with the correction and close-voting as typo is quicker.

Comment: I'd prefer to reword the standard close reason a bit, to extend for _'simle misconceptions'_, _'easy to find reference documentation'_, etc. to extend from just `typographical errors`, but stuff that ranges no the same level. I have to admit being using that close reason for this category of questions (wrongly). The problem might be that the available duplicates are really too many.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the idea of the "general reference" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason), @πάνταῥεῖ? See also [General reference questions create low-quality dead ends for Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160565) for more on the subject.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, not yet! Would this cover _'common misconceptions'_ also? I've just noticed, I have 2 very stupid typos in my comment above (_'simle => simple'_, _'no => on'_)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, potentially, although I should warn you before you get your hopes up that there's a near-nil chance of it ever being implemented at this point. I just thought you'd like to know the idea was out there.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks for the links related to "general reference".

Comment: Sure thing, @RSahu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's no typo; the OP clearly didn't initialize his variable, so you can't close it for that reason.

A typo would be:

> Why doesn't my code compile?
>
> ```
> char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2]: //Whoops! : instead of ;
> ```

Ok, thats a bad question anyways; but you could close it for the "typo" reason.

Your post sounds like the beginning of an answer to the question; though I would make sure to explain *why* the variable needs to be initialized here. The question could also be a duplicate, so you should check for that as well.

Comment: It's questionable if a missing initialization (which is actually required for valid c++ code), should not count as a _'typo'_ (it's not a literal one of course).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't recall the post, but I remember a meta answer saying that the typo reason are for *literal typos*. Like questions where you forgot a semicolon. "Simple changes to the code" does not necessarily make for a typo (and the code will compile in this case).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, your answer addresses my second question. Are you implying "yes" as the answer to the first question?

Comment: @RSahu I'm saying its not clear. The question is likely a duplicate (and so should be closed) but otherwise, it matches no close reason that I know of.